# How do I add a new line for text in the add value expression in Just In Mind?

Tags: concatenation, newline, justinmind

I am trying to make a list for example, food and their price in the value field of the rectangle using events.

```
Sausage $10
Hamburger $10
```

The expression that I have so far to create this is:

```
Sausage CONCAT (Space) CONCAT $10 CONCAT \n CONCAT Hamburger (SPACE) CONCAT $10
```

But that expression above will become this:

```
Sausage $10\nHamburger $10
```

But the \n does not work, I've tried to find methods on how to create a new line in the add value expression interface.

Please help, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- create a text widget, set it as multi-line
- set the text to '\n' (i.e. delete the text and hit ctrl+enter)
- use the widget's value when calculating the expression:

  - Sausage CONCAT (Space) CONCAT $10 CONCAT ***multiline_widget.value*** CONCAT Hamburger (SPACE) CONCAT $10
  - or: Sausage CONCAT (Space) CONCAT $10 CONCAT ***substring (multiline_widget.value, 0, 1)***  CONCAT Hamburger (SPACE) CONCAT $10